# How can I control what CMake generator is used when using the CMake Tools extension for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm using the CMake Tools extension for VS Code and want to control what CMake generator is used. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the `cmake.generator` and `cmake.preferredGenerators` settings contributed by the CMake Tools extension ([docs here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings)).

If you're using [CMake Presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) (and the associated support for them in CMake Tools), then you should just use the `generator` property of your configure presets. Then select the preset you want to use and that generator will be honoured.

If you're using [Kits](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/kits.html) (A CMake-Tools-specific feature), you can define a preferred generator for your kits using the `preferredGenerator` property. You can edit user-local kits using the `CMake: Edit User-Local CMake Kits` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Or you can define project-specific kits in `.vscode/cmake-kits.json`.

---

I'd suggest using CMake Presets as they're the most portable in that the feature is specified by CMake and is therefore IDE-agnostic, which makes for easier sharing and collaboration with other people using different development tools. If you actually want to define configuration presets to *not* share with others, CMake Presets supports that too in the form of CMakeUserPresets.json files.

If you're working on a hobby project you'll never share with anyone and only ever use one CMake generator and VS Code with, then sure, using the `cmake.generator` setting and kits is fine. If you're working on a lot of small one-off projects, then setting `cmake.generator` in your user settings (as opposed to workspace settings) would probably be helpful.